# How to pass float as argument (inline-assembly)?

Tags: c++, assembly, x86, inline-assembly, calling-convention

How to pass float as function argument (external call) and return float in inline assembly? An example below doesn't work and is crashing the app. The comments are mine, so they might be also wrong.

The first two lines are added by myself just for this example. Originally I start with two float values on st(0) and st(1) and there's nothing I can do about that.

```
fld     a               ; load float 'a' on st(0)
fld     b               ; load float 'b' on st(0), 'a' is now st(1)
sub     esp, 4          ; make room for float 
fstp    dword ptr [esp] ; push st(0) on stack, pop st(0)
mov     ecx, ebp        ; move 'this' on ecx
call    Class::ModValue ; returns float on st(0)
fcompp                  ; compare returned st(0) with st(1)    
fnstsw  ax
test    ah, 41h
jnz     Exit_label
```

The code snippet above is inside `asm{}` block, there is more unimportant code before and after that. The crash is happening between 1st line of this code fragment and `ModValue` function call.

Function signature:

```
float Class::ModValue(float value)
{
    _LOG("ModValue") // doesn't show
    return value;
}
```

Compiler: VisualStudio, Architecture: x86, Calling convention: `__thiscall`

Comment: IIRC, `__thiscall` is like most 32-bit calling conventions, and passes FP args in memory (above ESP in the same place you'd find integers.  The call-stack, not the x87 register stack).  FP values are returned in `st(0)`.

Comment: This isn't a [mcve].  Is this *inline* assembly inside an `asm{}` block in C++, or is it in a separate .asm file?  If the latter, how are you calling it, and obviously it crashes because there's no `ret` at the end of your function.  Crashes how, on which instruction?  Use your debugger.

Comment: @PeterCordes thanks for suggestions, edited the question with more info. It's inside `asm{}` block in C++

Comment: Show the surrounding code for a [mcve], and also the prototype for `Class::ModValue`.  I think `__thiscall` is a caller-pops convention, in which case the crash would be explained by leaving the inline-asm block with ESP modified.  Use `pop eax` after the function call to remove args from the stack.  Unlike the other registers (which MSVC notices when you clobber), MSVC assumes you don't modify ESP, I think.

Comment: Also, you can use [`fcomip`](https://github.com/HJLebbink/asm-dude/wiki/FCOMI_FCOMIP__FUCOMI_FUCOMIP) to compare directly into EFLAGS, if your code will run on CPUs made this century.  (New in PPro).  It only pops the x87 stack once, though. 
 Also, do you really need to use legacy x87 instead of SSE?  Normally you can assume at least SSE2 (Pentium4 / Athlon64), and almost certainly SSE1 for just single-precision (Pentium III / Athlon XP)

Comment: Presumably `ebp` doesn't hold a pointer to an object, so you're passing a bogus `this` (in `ecx`) to a class member function.  It probably isn't *pointing to* a valid pointer either, but you're just copying the register, not loading from memory.  Can't answer for sure without a [mcve], though.

Comment: @PeterCordes the whole function is too long to post it here, but I added `Class::ModValue` signature to original question. I don't receive the LOG message, so something is wrong with the call, not with return.  `__thiscall` cleans itself, I'm using exactly the same example with `int` and `push` (without cleaning anything after call) and it works fine. Just floats args are pushed differently. I'm wondering if I wasn't supposed to put some offset here `[esp+x]` or something like that?

Comment: The point of a [mcve] is to cut down your code until it's a lot simpler but still has the same problem.  This can take a bit of work if your starting point is a big function, but it's the only way to make questions with much future use or searchability.  Or even ones that can be answered at all without guessing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if it's a `__thiscall`

According to msdn:

*The __thiscall calling convention is used on member functions and is the default calling convention used by C++ member functions that do not use variable arguments. Under __thiscall, the callee cleans the stack, which is impossible for vararg functions. Arguments are pushed on the stack from right to left, with the this pointer being passed via register ECX, and not on the stack, on the x86 architecture.*

source: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ek8tkfbw.aspx

then a small example:

```
float DoStuffs(void *pThis, float a)
{
    float flResult = 0.0f;

    __asm
    {
        push a;
        mov ecx, pThis;
        call Class::ModValue;
        fstp[flResult];
    }
    return flResult;
}
```

Some extended example:

```
class Test
{
public:
    float b;   
    float Add(float a);

};

float Test::Add(float a)
{
    return a + this->b;
}

float CallTest(void* pThis, float x)
{
    float flResult = 0.0f;

    __asm
    {
        push x;
        mov ecx, pThis;
        call Test::Add;
        fstp[flResult];
    }

    return flResult;
}

int main()
{
    void* m = malloc(4);

    *(float*)m = 2.0f;

    std::cout << CallTest(m, 2.1f) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `add esp, 4` is incorrect after calling a `__thiscall` function, according to the docs you quoted:  "Under __thiscall, the callee cleans the stack"